# Referencing a textbox in ms access 2010 for query

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a form named: fail_reason
With 1 table inside named: reason (this table only has 1 field, with a header name of failure_reason)

I'm trying to use a textbox named 'searchbox' to find a value from that table and use a listbox to display the items.

I use:

```
Listbox101.rowsource = "select * from reason where reason.failure_reason like '* searchbox.text *'"
```

But the list box is always empty, its like its not reading the value of my textbox.

But when I define a value it works, ex:

```
Listbox101.rowsource = "select * from reason where reason.failure_reason like '* incomplete requirements *'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"SELECT * from reason WHERE failure_reason like '*" & searchbox & "*'"
```

Comment: You have space after the star.

Comment: thanks for the reply. it did it but is there a way I can use my textbox only? tia